# Can a flow (a set of maps) be defined with a Markov process?

Tags: differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

**Question** Can a *flow* include a Markov process?

A *flow* $\{\varphi_t\}$ is a set of maps $\varphi_t: X \to X\ \forall t\in R$ paramterised by $t$ that form a lie algebra on composition,
$$
\varphi_t\circ\varphi_s = \varphi_{t+s}\\
\varphi_t^{-1} = \varphi_{-t}\\
\varphi_0 = e
$$
where $e$ is the identity operation on $X$.

**First thoughts** If a flow were to include some Markov process it seems to me that negating the parameter $t$ would not give the inverse map at $t$ since
$$
\varphi_t\circ\varphi_{-t} \ne e
$$
where the random process causes the difference.

**Possible Resolution** The first thought as provided has assumed that $t$ has progressed from $t\to t+\delta t$ and provides a notational confusion. If the exact map that was defined at $t$ is inverted then it should contain the same random number that was generated at $t$ else it is not the same map and represents another map in the flow.

I think I have resolved the question to the answer *yes* but I am looking for a confirmation or a reasoned rebuttal

**Reference** [The Geometric Foundations of Hamiltonian Monte Carlo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5110v1%5Cnpapers2://publication/uuid/7D906BF6-2FFE-4AC3-9A60-C68E3CCBF6F7)